# AppSettings.json for Integration Test in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core, integration-testing, appsettings

I am following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing). I have a `Startup` in the API project that uses an `appsettings.json` configuration file.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)                
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
```

The particular part I'm looking at is the `env.ContentRootPath`. I did some digging around and it looks like my `appsettings.json` isn't actually copied to the `bin` folder but that is fine as `ContentRootPath` is returning `MySolution\src\MyProject.Api\`, which is where the `appsettings.json` file is located.

So in my integration test project I have this test:

```
public class TestShould
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public TestShould()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ReturnSuccessful()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/monitoring/test");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.Equal("Successful", responseString);
    }
```

This is basically copy and paste from the guide. When I debug this test, `ContentRootPath` is actually `MySolution\src\MyProject.IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\net461\`, which is obviously the build output folder for the test project and again the `appsettings.json` file is not there (yes I do have another `appsettings.json` file in the test project itself) so the test fails at creating the `TestServer`.

I tried getting around this by modifying the test `project.json` file.

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
        "includeFiles": [
            "appsettings.json"
       ]
    }
}
```

I hoped this would copy the `appsettings.json` file to the build output directory but it complains about the project missing a `Main` method for an entry point, treating the test project like a console project.

What can I do to get around this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end, I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing), specifically the **Integration Testing** section towards the bottom of the page. This removes the need to copy the `appsettings.json` file to the output directory. Instead it tells the test project the actual directory of the web application.

As for copying the `appsettings.json` to the output directory, I also managed to get that to work. Combined with the answer from *dudu*, I used `include` instead of `includeFiles` so the resulting section would look something like this:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": {
        "include": "appsettings.json"
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works but it does. I had a quick look at the documentation but couldn't find any real differences and since the original problem was essentially solved I didn't look further.

Comment: From my understanding: during test, when you use the target application root as content root and/or base path (instead of the test output directory), your application `Startup` will use its own `appsettings.json`, as when running outside of tests. In such scenario, copying test project  `appsettings.json` to its output directory will have no effect. That json file will not be read at all. Is that your experience?

Comment: How to do that in .NET.Core 2.0? the `project.json` was deprecated.

Comment: hi @Kevin Lee can you specify the actually code you used instead of pointing to the guide? Sometimes Microsoft changes documentation in last two years, thanks

Answer (score 21):

**Integration test** on **ASP.NET.Core 2.0** follow [MS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing?view=aspnetcore-2.0) ,

You should right click `appsettings.json` set its property `Copy to Output directory` to **Copy always**

And now you could find the json file in output folder, and build `TestServer` with

```
var projectDir = GetProjectPath("", typeof(TStartup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseEnvironment("Development")
    .UseContentRoot(projectDir)
    .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(projectDir)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build()
    )
    .UseStartup<TestStartup>());



/// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136848/3634867
/// <summary>
/// Gets the full path to the target project that we wish to test
/// </summary>
/// <param name="projectRelativePath">
/// The parent directory of the target project.
/// e.g. src, samples, test, or test/Websites
/// </param>
/// <param name="startupAssembly">The target project's assembly.</param>
/// <returns>The full path to the target project.</returns>
private static string GetProjectPath(string projectRelativePath, Assembly startupAssembly)
{
    // Get name of the target project which we want to test
    var projectName = startupAssembly.GetName().Name;

    // Get currently executing test project path
    var applicationBasePath = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;

    // Find the path to the target project
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBasePath);
    do
    {
        directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;

        var projectDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, projectRelativePath));
        if (projectDirectoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            var projectFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(projectDirectoryInfo.FullName, projectName, $"{projectName}.csproj"));
            if (projectFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                return Path.Combine(projectDirectoryInfo.FullName, projectName);
            }
        }
    }
    while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);

    throw new Exception($"Project root could not be located using the application root {applicationBasePath}.");
}
```

Ref: [TestServer w/ WebHostBuilder doesn't read appsettings.json on ASP.NET Core 2.0, but it worked on 1.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1191)

Comment: hi @John_J can you help answer this question also? thanks,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318131/net-core-integration-test-run-startup-cs-and-configuration-from-other-program

Comment: hi @John_J what is ProjectDir? Does it become the path of the actual project, or path of the actual project build artifacts, say bin-debug type folder? Please specify in answer, thanks – Also, if you are testing, how do point to the original Application startup? GetCurrentDirectory is directory for test project, not real project correct?

Comment: Hi @JeremyWatkins , the `contentRoot` is where your .csproj file is. I use "GetProjectPath" of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136848/3634867

Comment: @user11721944 ,  as the method description, ProjectDir is "Gets the full path to the target project that we wish to test" not test project dir. just give it a try : )

Answer (score 1):

Remove `"emitEntryPoint": true` in test `project.json` file.

Comment: That got rid of the error about it missing a `Main` but it didn't copy the `appsettings.json` into the `bin` directory.